# Why do I have this error when I try to submit a comment without adding Name and/or body?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am facing this problem(please check the picture).
I want when I click on "Submit" without typing body and/or email, to show that those fields are required. I am currently a beginner, and I've tried to deal with the error, but I couldn't. Please Help.

[image: ERROR]

This is my model:

```
             <?php 
  class Comment_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct() {
    $this->load->database(); //database library loaded
}

public function create_comment($post_id) {
    $data = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'body' => $this->input->post('body')

    );

    return $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
}

public function get_comments($post_id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('comments', array('post_id' => $post_id));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

}

This is my comment controller:

```
                          <?php 
  class Comments extends CI_Controller {
  public function create($post_id) {
    $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');


    }
    else {
        $this->comment_model->create_comment($post_id);
        redirect('posts/'.$slug);
    }
}
```

}

Post controller:

```
       public function view($slug = NULL) {
       $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);

    $post_id = $data['post']['id'];
    $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_comments($post_id);
    
    if(empty($data['post'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And view:
`code`

```
              <h3>Comments</h3>
<?php if($comments) : ?>
    <?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>
        <div class="jumbotron bg-dark">
            <h5><?php echo $comment['body']; ?> [by <strong><?php echo $comment['name']; ?></strong>]</h5>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p>No Comments to Display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please add the error message as text instead of an image. Then it makes it easier for us to copy/paste potential message when writing answers, and it makes the question more searchable (if others have similar errors)

Comment: You only add `$data['comments']` in your Post controller, but not in your Comment controller, but you seem to be loading the same view in both (which I'm assuming contains the view code you've posted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view try like this

```
<?php if(!empty($comments)) : ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if($comments) : ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `comments` from $data is missing in your Comment controller.
Use `empty()` to check if a variable is present or not in your view